# set and play system sound in IOS5 with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, audiotoolbox

i've spent some time searching and there is probably is an easy way to set and play system sound using ARC but all i found is non ARC compatible. If someone has a snippet I would be very grateful.

Figured it out now.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code you've tried.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, hope someone will find it useful too.

**.h file:**

```
@property (readwrite) CFURLRef sysSoundTestPath;
```

**.m file:**

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@synthesize sysSoundTestPath;
SystemSoundID soundID;


NSURL *path   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"testSound" withExtension: @"wav"];
sysSoundTestPath = (__bridge CFURLRef)path;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(sysSoundTestPath, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: You also need to add `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Comment: Thanks, Lewis, I added it to the solution